# using Linq to generate a collection of things to be removed from another collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections, loops

I'm familiar with the problem of modifying a collection while looping over it with a `foreach` loop (i.e. "System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified").  However, it doesn't make sense to me that when I use Linq to create a List of keys to delete from a dictionary, then loop over my new List, I get the same exception.

Code before, that threw an exception:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> keysToDelete = _outConnections.Where(
    pair => pair.Value < timeoutPoint
).Select(pair => pair.Key);

foreach (Guid key in keysToDelete)
{
    ...some stuff not dealing with keysToDelete...
    _outConnections.Remove(key);
}
```

Code after, that worked:

```
List<Guid> keysToDelete = _outConnections.Where(
    pair => pair.Value < timeoutPoint
).Select(pair => pair.Key).ToList();

for (int i=keysToDelete.Count-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    Guid key = keysToDelete[i];
    ...some stuff not dealing with keysToDelete...
    _outConnections.Remove(key);
}
```

Why is this?  I have the feeling that maybe my Linq queries aren't really returning a new collection, but rather some subset of the original collection, hence it accuses me of modifying the collection `keysToDelete` when I remove an element from `_outConnections`.

**Update:**  the following fix also works, thanks to Adam Robinson:

```
List<Guid> keysToDelete = _outConnections.Where(
    pair => pair.Value < timeoutPoint
).Select(pair => pair.Key).ToList();

foreach (Guid key in keysToDelete)
{
    ...some stuff not dealing with keysToDelete...
    _outConnections.Remove(key);
}
```

Comment: If I could tell people just one thing about LINQ queries it's that the result of a query expression is *the query itself*, not *the results of the query*. This common misunderstanding underlies a considerable fraction of the questions about LINQ on StackOverflow.

Comment: When I discovered Linq, I thought "oh hey, this lets me do stuff like in Ruby!", and I still internally think of methods like `Select` and `Where` in terms of Ruby's `map` and `select`, which do the processing and return a new collection of results.  I'll have to start mentally separating the Ruby methods from similar-seeming Linq methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're correct. LINQ uses what's called "deferred execution". Declaring your LINQ query *doesn't actually do anything* other than construct a query expression. It isn't until you actually enumerate over the list that the query is evaluated, and it uses the original list as the source.

However, calling `ToList()` should create a brand new list that has no relation to the original. Check the call stack of your exception to ensure that it is actually being thrown by `keysToDelete`.

Comment: Whoops, forgot that part of my fix involved adding the `ToList`.  Originally, I just worked with the `IEnumerable`; updated question code to reflect this.

Comment: Oho, based on your second paragraph, I could alter my fix to one of the following:  1) remove the `ToList` stuff and just use my `for` loop over the `IEnumerable` or 2) keep the `ToList` stuff and switch back to using a `foreach` loop since the new List is a separate collection.  Thanks!

Comment: You can't use the `for` option, since `IEnumerable` doesn't support index-based access. I would recommend switching to a `foreach` over the result of the `ToList()`.

Comment: Agreed.  I don't like those simple `for` loops because they don't seem nearly as safe as a `foreach`.  I added my new solution (`ToList` with `foreach`) to the question.